# $P$ and $Q$ are subsets of ${(a_1,a_2,a_3...a_n)}$ chosen at random. Find the probability that $Q$ is a subset of $P$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

$P$ and $Q$ are subsets of ${(a_1,a_2,a_3...a_n)}$ chosen at random. Find the probability that $Q$ is a subset of $P$.

I chose $r$ elements from the set for $P$, then $Q$. could have $0,1,2...(r-1)$ elements from those $r$. Thus total would be (ignoring edge case of $r=0$ and such for now) $$\sum {n \choose r}({r \choose 0}+{r \choose 1}...+{r \choose r})$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum{n \choose r}(2^r)$$
I am not sure how to solve this further

I also thought of another way, in which we select $r$ elements that are common first, and then decide if the rest are in $P$ or not in $P$. $$\sum{n \choose r}(2^{n-r})$$
But it gives a similar expression so I wasn't able to solve this either

Comment: $({3 \over 4})^n$ maybe?

Comment: Are we assuming that each subset is selected with equal probability?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't have the answer, but numerically for two small values of $n$ the manual sum of the above expression comes out to be the same as what you say. Did I miss something trivial?

Comment: @RobertShore yes

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr 2^r=(1+2)^n = 3^n$

Comment: @l1mbo If the subsets are uniformly and independently selected then an element is in a set with probability ${1 \over 2}$. If $n=1$ there are 3 possibilities for it to be a subset, hence the ${1 \over 4}$. Repeating for $n$ elements gives the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked, here is an approach that uses a binomial series.

Take $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Partition your sample space $2^A\times 2^A$ based on the size of $P$  to say $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(Q\subseteq P) &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathbb{P}(Q\subseteq P,|P|=k) \\ &=& \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\big|\big\{(P,Q)\in2^A \times 2^A: Q\subseteq P, |P|=k\big\}\big|}{\big|2^A \times 2^A\big|} \\ &=&\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2^k{n \choose k}}{4^n} \\ &=&\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}2^k1^{n-k} \\ &=& \frac{1}{4^n}(1+2)^n \\ &=& (3/4)^n\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

We need, for each element $a_k$, that it is not the case that $a_k$ is in $Q$ but not in $P$. That is, for each element, there are four possibilities (in both sets, in neither, in $P$ but not $Q$, in $Q$ but not $P$). Out of these four possibilities, only one precludes $Q$ from being a subset of $P$.

If we assume that "chosen at random" means that a subset is constructed by giving each element an independent 50% chance of being in the subset, then these four possibilities have the same probability as each other, so the probability of getting the "wrong" one is $\frac 1 4$, and the probability of getting one of the "right" ones is $\frac 3 4$. The probability of getting the "right" one for all $n$ elements is $\left(\frac 3 4\right)^n$.

Comment: Wow that is such a simple way to think about it! As a separate question, do you know how the binomial series could be solved to give the same answer?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give logical solution without any calculation.
What we can note is that there is no condition on elements of P. Only condition is on the elements of Q that they must be present in P as well. Let $Pr_i$(valid) be the probability that $i^{th}$ element satisfies the given condition.
So, following are the possible cases for the $i^{th}$ element:

1. $i^{th}$ element is present in Q. Now it must be also present on P. $Pr_i$(valid) = $\left(\frac 1 2\right)$*$\left(\frac 1 2\right)$ = $\left(\frac 1 4\right)$.
2. $i^{th}$ element is not present in Q. Now, there is no other condition. Hence, $Pr_i$(valid) = $\left(\frac 1 2\right)$.

On summing both cases, $Pr_i$(valid) = $\left(\frac 1 4\right)$+$\left(\frac 1 2\right)$ = $\left(\frac 3 4\right)$.
There are $n$ such elements, hence final probability $Pr_{total}$(valid) will be $\left(\frac 3 4\right)^n$ as all $n$ elements are independent of each other.